# What's the difference of lifecycle and plugins of Mavin in IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

On the right side of IDEA, there are many similar buttons in the window of Maven. Among them, both lifecycle and plugins can compile. What is the difference between them? Is it different from using the `mvn compile` in the terminal directly?

[image]

Comment: May help: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, [you're expected to do your own research before asking a question here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/5698098). – If you know Maven then _Lifecycle_ and _Plugins_ should be clear to you; IntelliJ simply gives you a GUI _Maven Tool Window_ to interact with it, see also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html.

Answer (score 0):

Lifecycle node shows the [Maven lifecycle phases and goals](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) that are available for this project. The other node shows the goals that ech plugin which is configured in project has. These could be same goals or specific goals which are not bound to lifecycle.